# Hardware resources for web testing with selenium/webdriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I need to run multiple websites test/loads and I would like to know what CPU (make, model) I need to buy to run simultaneously 40-50 chrome tabs opened from the scripts.

Currently, with an I3340 (quad-core, 3,3GHZ) I can open 8 test instances and the  CPU load is 100%. Does anyone have an idea? I need NOT run a headless browser.

Thank you!